# Python: Faster or Loop-Free Way of Assigning Points to Bins?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have an N-by-2 array of N 2D points, which I want to assign to an M-by-K grid of bins.

For instance, points `[m + 0.1, k]` and `[m + 0.1, k + 0.9]` should fall into bin `[m, k]`, where both `m` and `k` are integers. It's possible that a point doesn't fall into any of the bins.

Implementation-wise, I want the result stored in a logical M-by-K-by-N array `in_bin`, where `in_bin[m, k, n]` is `True`, if point `n` falls into bin `[m, k]`.

Here is how I'm doing this, naively with double loops.

```
M = 10
K = 11
N = 100
pts = 20 * np.random.rand(N, 2)
in_bin = np.zeros((M, K, N), dtype=bool)
for m in range(M):
    for k in range(K):
        inbin_h = (pts[:, 0] >= m) & (pts[:, 0] < (m + 1))
        inbin_w = (pts[:, 1] >= k) & (pts[:, 1] < (k + 1))
        in_bin[m, k, np.where(inbin_h & inbin_w)[0]] = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` isn't actually needed (not that this changes speed much):

```
In [120]: in_bin1 = np.zeros((M, K, N), dtype=bool) 
     ...: for m in range(M): 
     ...:     for k in range(K): 
     ...:         inbin_h = (pts[:, 0] >= m) & (pts[:, 0] < (m + 1)) 
     ...:         inbin_w = (pts[:, 1] >= k) & (pts[:, 1] < (k + 1)) 
     ...:         in_bin1[m, k, inbin_h & inbin_w] = True
```

But we can do the allocation for all `m` and `k` at once:

```
In [125]: x0=(pts[:,0]>=np.arange(M)[:,None]) & (pts[:,0]<np.arange(1,M+1)[:,None]);                                                            
In [126]: x1=(pts[:,1]>=np.arange(K)[:,None]) & (pts[:,1]<np.arange(1,K+1)[:,None]);  
In [127]: x0.shape                                                           
Out[127]: (10, 100)
In [128]: x1.shape                                                           
Out[128]: (11, 100)
```

combine these with broadcasting:

```
In [129]: xx = x0[:,None,:] & x1[None,:,:]                                   
In [130]: xx.shape                                                           
Out[130]: (10, 11, 100)
In [131]: np.allclose(in_bin1, xx)    # and check                                        
Out[131]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `histogram2d` as follows:

```
hist = np.dstack(np.histogram2d([pts[i,0]],[pts[i,1]],bins=[np.arange(M+1),np.arange(K+1)])[0] for i in range(len(pts)))
```

which only involves a single for loop over the number of points. If N is much smaller than M*K this should be faster.

Here is another method without any for loops using `searchsorted` which is what `histogram2d` uses:

```
def bin_points(pts, m, k):
    binsx = np.arange(m+1)
    binsy = np.arange(k+1)
    index_x = np.searchsorted(binsx,pts[:,0]) - 1
    index_y = np.searchsorted(binsy,pts[:,1]) - 1
    # mask out values which fall outside the bins
    mask = (index_x >= 0) & (index_x < m) & (index_y >= 0) & (index_y < k)
    index_x = index_x[mask]
    index_y = index_y[mask]
    n = np.arange(pts.shape[0])[mask]
    in_bin = np.zeros((M, K, pts.shape[0]), dtype=bool)
    in_bin[index_x,index_y,n] = 1
```

Here are some benchmarks:

*M = 10, K = 11, N = 100*

```
In [2]: %timeit bin_points(pts,M,K)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.1 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit bin_points_double_for_loop(pts,M,K)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit bin_points_broadcast(pts,M,K)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.6 µs per loop
```

*M = 100, K = 110, N = 1000*

```
In [2]: %timeit bin_points(pts,M,K)
1000 loops, best of 3: 721 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit bin_points_double_for_loop(pts,M,K)
1 loop, best of 3: 249 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit bin_points_broadcast(pts,M,K)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.04 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks -- didn't know about that before. In my case, actually N is much larger than M*K. Is this solution any good in this case?

Comment: In that case it probably wouldn't work as well as your method, but I added a new method which should avoid any python for loops.

Answer (score 2):

We are checking if those floating pt numbers in `pts` are in each integer bin at each iteration. So, the trick we could use would be to convert those floating pt numbers to their floored-down numbers. Additionally, we need to mask out the valid ones that satisfy the `range(M)` and `range(N)`. That's all there is!

Here's the implementation -

```
def binpts(pts, M, K):
    N = len(pts)
    in_bin_out = np.zeros((M, K, N), dtype=bool)
    mask = (pts[:,0]<M) & (pts[:,1]<K)
    pts_f = pts[mask]
    r,c = pts_f.astype(int).T
    in_bin_out[r, c, mask] = 1
    return in_bin_out
```

---

#### Benchmarking

Timings on large arrays with the range in the floating pts array proportional to its size as provided in given sample -

Case #1 :

```
In [2]: M = 100
   ...: K = 101
   ...: N = 10000
   ...: np.random.seed(0)
   ...: pts = 2000 * np.random.rand(N, 2)

# @hpaulj's soln
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: x0=(pts[:,0]>=np.arange(M)[:,None]) & (pts[:,0]<np.arange(1,M+1)[:,None])
   ...: x1=(pts[:,1]>=np.arange(K)[:,None]) & (pts[:,1]<np.arange(1,K+1)[:,None])
   ...: xx = x0[:,None,:] & x1[None,:,:]
10 loops, best of 3: 47.5 ms per loop

# @user545424's soln
In [6]: %timeit bin_points(pts,M,K)
1000 loops, best of 3: 331 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit binpts(pts,M,K)
10000 loops, best of 3: 125 µs per loop
```

Note :
@hpaulj's soln is memory intensive and I ran out of memory using it on larger ones.

Case #2 :

```
In [8]: M = 100
   ...: K = 101
   ...: N = 100000
   ...: np.random.seed(0)
   ...: pts = 20000 * np.random.rand(N, 2)

In [9]: %timeit bin_points(pts,M,K)
   ...: %timeit binpts(pts,M,K)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 585 µs per loop
```

Case #3 :

```
In [10]: M = 100
    ...: K = 101
    ...: N = 1000000
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: pts = 200000 * np.random.rand(N, 2)

In [11]: %timeit bin_points(pts,M,K)
    ...: %timeit binpts(pts,M,K)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop
```